# How to hide paragraph when checkbox is checked in REACTjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie in REACT.  I created a form with a few components.  In one of the components, I have a checkbox and a paragraph with text in it.  I can't figure out how to hide the paragraph when the checkbox is clicked.  The boolean is captured in state but not sure how to use it to do what I want.

```
class Anonymous extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
  anon:false
}
  this.anonymousBox = this.anonymousBox.bind(this)
}

anonymousBox(event){
  this.setState({anon:event.target.checked})
}

render(){
  return(
  <span>
  <input type="checkbox" 
    name="anon" value="" 
    onChange={this.anonymousBox}
    checked={this.state.anon}
  /> Anonymous

  <p style={{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
    First Name: <br />
    Last Name: <br />
    Email: <br />
    Country: <br />
    Phone: <br />
  </p>
 </span>
  )
 }
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/mdejbvy?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally render the paragraph based on the state like so:

```
{this.state.anon && <p style={{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
  First Name: <br />
  Last Name: <br />
  Email: <br />
  Country: <br />
  Phone: <br />
</p>}
```

This is similar (see comment by Drew below) to this style of conditional rendering:

```
{this.state.someBoolean ? <p>Some text</p> : null}
```

I.e, if a condition is met than render this piece of jsx, else don't render nothing.

Another option would be to toggle a CSS class with a `display: none` property. That would look something like that:

```
<p className={this.state.anon ? "show" : "hide"} style={{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
  First Name: <br />
  Last Name: <br />
  Email: <br />
  Country: <br />
  Phone: <br />
</p>
```

Of course you'll need the corresponding CSS classes to make this work.
You can also use the ternary conditions inside of the inline styles:

```
<p style={{ backgroundColor:'yellow', display: this.state.anon ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
  First Name: <br />
  Last Name: <br />
  Email: <br />
  Country: <br />
  Phone: <br />
</p>
```

In the last two options, you can substitute `display: none` with `visibility: hidden` which [behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133064/11220086).

You can read more about using the ternary operators in jsx in the React docs for [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Which of the options is better depends on the use case, so it's up to you!

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: FYI `condition && Component` is not equivalent to `condition ? Component : null`. Consider this `dataArray.length && Component`: if the data array is empty and length 0 (falsey), then the length 0 will output to rendered result whereas using the ternary will correctly return null.

Comment: Try this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-wildflower-ogorh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark

Comment: I understand the answers except ```condition && Component```.  Is the component considered a boolean?

Comment: `Component` here refers to a React component or any other HTML element. Ternaries are expressions that evaluate to booleans. So `Component` have a truthy value (somewhat like non-empty strings or non-zero numbers), and if condition is `true` than `Component` is rendered because the entire expression evaluates to `true`. If condition is `false` than the entire expression evaluates to `false` and Component isn't rendered. Think of it like `true && true === true` which means render, and `false && true === false` which means do not render.